# best practice to present multiple images in paper

Tags: graphics, floats

I want to present 8 images one by one. This is an evolution of a system, so the images should be big that reader can spot the difference. I want two images on a single page. The problem is  that default latex formatting put text in every free space between images. Tex:

```
bla bla

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{01}
    \caption{ 2000K.}
\end{figure} 

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{02}
    \caption{1500K.}
\end{figure} 

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{09}
    \caption{1100K.}
\end{figure} 

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{11}
    \caption{1000K.}
\end{figure} 

%---------------

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{14}
    \caption{ 900K.}
\end{figure} 

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{17}
    \caption{ 850K.}
\end{figure} 

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{21}
    \caption{ 750K.}
\end{figure} 

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{31}
    \caption{400K.}
\end{figure} 

 bla bla
```

I could force the formatting with `\newpage`, but it seems that there should be a better way.

Comment: If you are using only the `h!` option anyway, maybe it's better not to use floats at all. Instead just insert every picture with `\includegraphics` at the place where it's supposed to be.

Comment: And how to add caption?

Comment: use `captionof` from the `caption` package

Comment: I have seen some floats with a H specifier, which means force the float to be here I.e. you get the benefits of the float environment with the knowledge that the float won't move in the document. I don't recall if this works for figures though.

Answer (score 2):

As alternative to avoid floats, use only the option `p` (page of floats) in the figures. If needed, use `\clearpage` to forcing also the process of accumulated floats instead of `\newpage` that only ends the current page (or column), may be allowing to some floats to start in the new page.